# How to customise the dropdown of React-select library more than given in the documentation

Tags: react-select

I want to customise the layout of drop-down of React select library more than given in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
we can do the customization in two ways.
1) applying **inline style** as given below:
render(){const optionStyle={width: 100px};return(<div style={optionStyle}><select><option value="a">A</option><option value="b">B</option></select></div>
);}; 
2) another way is applying **stylesheet** as follows:
import React from 'react';import './style.css';class OptionComponent extends React.Component{render()return<div className="row"><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></div>);};}
className = "row" is the css class "row".
```